# SQL Server Management Studio deny view access to all databases but the ones user has access to without making user owner

Tags: sql-server, privileges

I'm using SQL Server 2014/2016. Is it possible to deny a user(s) view access to all database but the ones they have access to without making the user owner?

I don't want the user to have owner permissions as well as I'll be adding multiple users to the database.

I've gone through a lot of threads and it doesn't seem like you can but it seems like an obvious feature that people may want so I'm not too sure.

```
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO userName
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE:: [DbName] TO userName
```

Regards

Comment: What do you mean with "view access"? You mean particular view objects? See the database name in the drop-down in SSMS?

Comment: If a **`LOGIN`** (not `USER`) has the permission `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE` then they can only see the database they themselves own in `sys.databases`; that is by design. As a result, the object explorer will not display these other databases, as SSMS uses the `sys` objects to populate them.

Comment: Hi EzLo: yes that's what i mean